# Write the model as an object available in Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

first time using Asp.Net MVC here.
I have a model class defined with 3 properties and I would like to access this model from javascript code on the view.

The best I found was [this page](http://trycatchfail.com/blog/post/Exposing-the-View-Model-to-JavaScript-in-ASPNET-MVC.aspx)
It would allow me to do something like this:

```
<script>
 var model = <%= Model.ToJson() %>
 alert(model.Prop1);
</script>
```

Since this code is based on an article from 2007 I was wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd suspect that if there were anything seriously wrong with this approach then you'd have found lots of alternatives out there. I think the actuality is that most people don't find the need to push the entire Model down to the client javascript, I'm not sure I can think of a reason that I'd want to do that to be honest. What's driving your investigation here, it'd be interesting to learn your objective.

Comment: The data of my page will be updated with ajax regularly with timed requests from JSON, but I thought that I could render the initial data with Javascript by having the JSON as a var on the page directly, this way it won't need to wait for a AJAX callback to start filling the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's a very good way to achieve this. It uses `JavaScriptSerializer` to serialize your model into a JSON object and ensure proper escaping.

As an alternative if you are using AJAX you could directly have a controller action returning JSON:

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    var model = FetchTheModel();
    return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

and then using jquery consume this action:

```
$.getJSON('<%= Html.Action("Foo") %>', function(result) {
    alert(result.Prop1);
});
```

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? Please leave a comment when downvoting.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but afaik JavascriptSerializer is depricated, and you should use DataContractSerializer instead... I am not a c# guru tho

Comment: @Martin, JavaScriptSerializer is not deprecated. I don't know where did you read this. The just released ASP.NET MVC 3 framework uses it to generate JSON. In fact it was temporally deprecated in .NET 3.5 and undepretaced back in .NET 3.5 SP1. It's usage is perfectly fine.

Comment: It was deprecated at some point,. but seems to have been undeprecated again in .NET 3.5SP1.. try to google for "javascriptserializer deprecated" and you will get many results :)

Comment: Darin, a good answer. You are doing a great answers most of the time. Do not take this downvote into account. I upvoted your answer :-).

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for: return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);